# Get the sublist with a maximum value from a list

Tags: python, list, max, sublist

I am trying to retrieve the sublist with a maximum key value inside a list.

eg. In this example, I am trying to retrieve the sublist with maximum confidence score:

```
 listA=[{'id': '1', 'actions': [{'acc': 'ac1', 'coordinates': [569, 617, 627, 631], 'confidence': 93.0}]}, {'id': '1', 'actions': [{'acc': 'acc1','coordinates': [569, 617, 627, 631], 'confidence': 94.0}]}, {'id': '1', 'actions': [{'acc': 'acc1', 'coordinates': [569, 617, 627, 631], 'confidence': 95.0}]}]
```

The expected output is :

```
[{'id': '1', 'actions': [{'acc': 'acc1', 'coordinates': [569, 617, 627, 631], 'confidence': 95.0}]
```

I have used itemgetter but it is not returning the desired output.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: itemgetter which I have already mentioned. Please check.

Comment: Can there be multiple `actions`, and what should it do then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used python's max function and provided it with a key that will use the confidence key-value as the way to find the maximum.

```
listA=[{'id': '1', 'actions': [{'acc': 'ac1', 'coordinates': [569, 617, 627, 631], 'confidence': 93.0}]},
       {'id': '1', 'actions': [{'acc': 'acc1','coordinates': [569, 617, 627, 631], 'confidence': 94.0}]},
       {'id': '1', 'actions': [{'acc': 'acc1', 'coordinates': [569, 617, 627, 631], 'confidence': 95.0}]}]

maxList = max(listA, key=lambda x: x['actions'][0]['confidence'])
print(maxList)
```

You could do almost exactly the same thing if you wanted to return a sorted list of the items rather than just the maximum. You'd just replace `max` with `sorted`

EDIT: Thanks @tobias_k for the great suggestion. If there is more than one action, replace the lambda with `lambda x: max(a['confidence'] for a in x['actions'])`

Comment: Ah, 3 minutes earlier. I will delete my answer and upvote your's.

Comment: Well then: first time first. Hurray!

Comment: Or possibly `lambda x: max(a['confidence'] for a in x['actions'])` if there can be more than one.

Comment: @tobias_k Great suggestion! Wasn't sure whether the OP would need this or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution is you find lambda hard to understand.

I made it very verbose and beginner friendly so it can be used also by newcomers:

```
listA=[{'id': '1', 'actions': [{'acc': 'ac1', 'coordinates': [569, 617, 627, 631], 'confidence': 93.0}]}, {'id': '1', 'actions': [{'acc': 'acc1','coordinates': [569, 617, 627, 631], 'confidence': 94.0}]}, {'id': '1', 'actions': [{'acc': 'acc1', 'coordinates': [569, 617, 627, 631], 'confidence': 95.0}]}]

max_confidence_item = None
max_confidence_value = float('-inf') # This is just a VERY small number so that we are sure that every confidence we find as first is bigger than this number
for item in listA:
    current_confidence_value = item['actions'][0]['confidence']
    current_confidence_item = item
    if (max_confidence_value < current_confidence_value):
        max_confidence_value = current_confidence_value
        max_confidence_item = current_confidence_item
    
print(max_confidence_item)
```

**Output**

```
{'id': '1', 'actions': [{'confidence': 95.0, 'coordinates': [569, 617, 627, 631], 'acc': 'acc1'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
confidence = 0
i = 0

for _ in range(len(listA)):
    if confidence < listA[_]['actions'][0]['confidence']:
        i += 1
        confidence = listA[_]['actions'][0]['confidence']

print(listA[i -1])
```